# Meteor: rendered function called before documents are loaded

Tags: meteor, iron-router

I have a template with a rendered function like this:

```
Template.config.rendered = function () {
    var barfoo = BarFoo.findOne({....});

    if (barfoo) {
        $('[start-date]').datepicker({ ... });
    }
}
```

The problem is that the collection `BarFoo` is still empty at the time the `rendered` function is called.

I'm using [Iron Router](https://github.com/EventedMind/iron-router) so I can wait until specific subscriptions have loaded their documents:

```
HomeController = RouteController.extend({
    ...
    waitOn: function () {
        return Meteor.subscribe('barfoo');
    }
});
```

So the question is, how is it possible that the rendered function is called before the data of barfoo is loaded ?

Answer (score 1):

You could use `onData` in your routecontroller. If you use the `data` param:

```
data: function() {
    bar: BarFoo.findOne({....})
}
onData: function() {
    if(BarFoo.findOne({....})) {
        $('[start-date]').datepicker({ ... });
    }
}
```

`onData` is run every time the return value of `data` changes, so you can check if there is a value there first, it can also be reactively changed if your subscription changes.

Another option is to add a loading template, which is shown while your subscription completes:

```
loadingTemplate : 'template'
```

Comment: The problem with this solution is that you do specific template stuff in your controller. Also when I define a 'loading' template the rendered function is called before the loading template is shown. I found an other workaround which seems to work which is to define `Deps.autorun(function () { .... })` inside the rendered function

Comment: @JeanlucaScaljeri you can define a loading template per template I beleive too. The onData uses the `Deps.autorun` under the hood anyway. just be sure to run `.stop()` on the handle returned by it in your template destroyed callback to clean it up when you leave the template

Comment: a loading template per template that would be interesting, do you have any idea how to do that (or a link) ? and thnx a lot for the `.stop()` tip!